# Visual Basic VSTO plugin for Outlook: Show folder in active Explorer

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio, outlook, vsto

I had a working code in VBA, looking up a folder by name and then opening it in the main window like this:

```
Set LookupFolder = nSpace.Folders(mailboxNameLabel).Folders(destinationFolder)
```

When moving my project to Visual Studio (vb.net), I was told:

> 'Let' and 'Set' assignment statements are no longer supported

Just omitting the "Set" word, doesn't do the job, the folder does not open using this code:

```
LookupFolder = nSpace.Folders(mailboxNameLabel).Folders(destinationFolder)
```

If I use the "Display" methode, the folder will open in a new, minimized window:

```
nSpace.Folders(mailboxNameLabel).Folders(destinationFolder).Display()
```

How do I manage to open the folder in my active explorer (just "jump" to that folder as it worked before)?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder` property to the folder object.

Comment: Great! It works:
Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = LookupFolder (...)